# Problems with view rendering

Tags: php, kohana

I have a page with list of users in admin panel, it has a view with bootstrap table (users list). Today I noticed that it renders only half or less number of users. After refreshing the page the point in which it stops is different user (might be on 250's user or 1000's). The data from controller is full and solid, I checked it with printing users array. Here the picture of ending the view:[image]

And the code inside table:

```
 <? foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><strong><?= $item->id; ?></strong></td>
            <td>
                <?= $item->username ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $item->name ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $item->email ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $item->phone ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $item->remark ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span style="color: <?= $item->validated ? 'green' : 'gray' ?>"><?= $item->validated ? 'Активирован' : 'Не активирован'?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Действия <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="<?= Route::url('admin', array(
                                'controller' => $model->object_name(),
                                'action' => 'edit',
                                'id' => $item->id
                            )) ?>">Редактировать</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?= Route::url('admin', array(
                                'controller' => $model->object_name(),
                                'action' => 'delete',
                                'id' => $item->id
                            )) ?>">Удалить</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

**Error log** is empty

**UPD** When I try to open this page on the iphone, it starts to load it and the throws error "Operation could not be completed" error 303

Comment: Did you check the error log? How long does it take to load? Could it be a timeout? Or maybe a memory issue? How many rows are there?

Comment: What is the query to retrieve the users? did you specify there that you can only show a certain ammount (a limit) on it? You can check your php error log by if you click on the php file in the debugger what it returns. (you can see the post data but also the retrieve data)

Comment: @Dorvalla no, it gets all users (nearly 1700 records)

Answer (score 0):

Something goes wrong when you call $item->validated for your 250'th user.

```
<?= $item->validated ? 'green' : 'gray' ?>"><?= $item->validated ? 'Активирован' : 'Не активирован'?>
```

Check your php logs first and find your error.

Comment: I said the row and cell in which it stops is random

Comment: Then it looks like [execution timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or [memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Try to grow them up. First of all, disable time limit (set to zero).

Comment: What should I write for memory_limit? Is it a function?

Comment: @Eugene find your php.ini file (run `php -i | grep php.ini` in the terminal) then find memory_limit set and change value (-1 for no limit).

Comment: I can't set settings of php, I am using web housting without such possibilities

Comment: So that is a problem. You can try to change it right form PHP: ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); but hosting providers usually disable this way (like a php safe mode). I think you need to use paginator (or ajax infinity scroll). Big onepage data is not for hosting.